# Wrap shiny application in a package

Tags: r, shiny, package

I created a shiny to view data from the National High School Exam in Brazil. However, the database is very large. So I decided to encapsulate the shiny in a package. My idea is that when someone wants to view the shiny, they just need to install the package, use its functions to download the data and later generate the shiny. However, I don't know how to get the data to be saved to a location where shiny finds it and can compile it. How should I proceed?

Follow the link to my package: https://github.com/fsbmat-ufv/statenem

Package for generating shiny dashboard with data from Enem. To install it just use:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("fsbmat-ufv/statenem")
library(statenem)
```

The first functions to be used are:

```
enemdown(2018)
enemclear(2018)
```

Then, turn shiny with the command:

```
statenem::runExample()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you want people to install your package and then get access to the data? You can include data in the package itself, no need to host it elsewhere for extraction.

You can probably google "include dataset with package r", but [here's](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html) one of the links I found that goes into some detail on how to do this.

Comment: Sorry, friend. I know how to add a database to the package. That's not what I need! Since the database I use for shiny is very large, I can't keep it on github or run it on shinyapps.io. So, I wish that when using my package, people download the data with functions of my package and run shiny on their own machine!

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain a lot what you want to do, so it's not easy to help. I took a look at your package, and if I correctly understood I think you can do something like that:

```
runShinyApp <- function(year) {
  appDir <- system.file(......, package = "statenem")
  options(year = year)
  shiny::shinyAppDir(appDir)
}
```

And in your file `global.R`:

```
year <- getOption("year")
enemdown(year)
datos <- enemclear(year)
```

That is, the user executes `runShinyApp(2018)`, then the `runShinyApp` function sets the R option `year = 2018`, and this option is read in `global.R`, which downloads and cleans the data. There would be no `saveRDS`/`readRDS`.